# Solution doesn´t contain any folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am doing a WEB API C# .NET and after doing a commit push to my azure repository, the solution file doesn´t have any folder that is before that.
Here it is the image before clicking on solution that has all folders that i need

[image]

After clicking on my solution it doesn´t take any folder with him.

[image]

When i click view all files they look transparent like it isn´t recognisable

[image]

Can i make a new solution or reconfigure this one?

Comment: How did you end up with this setup in the first place? I guess you copy pasted the project into your solution from somewhere? if so you need to add the project to your solution/solution file take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/tutorial-projects-solutions?view=vs-2022

Comment: Just like i said i commit my project and on the next day i open at visual studio my folder project and i clicked at the solution and it disappeared. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The view in the first picture is called **Folder View**. You can switch to it with 2 steps.

1. Click the 4th button in **Solution Explorer**

   [image: Step1]
2. Double click **Folder View**

   [image: Step2]

---

---

To switch back to the **Solution View**.

1. Find and double click a sln file in the **Folder View**
2. If you cannot find a sln file, click **Show All Files** button in **Solution Explorer**

Comment: I have done what you said and it really shows all the folders inside solution. However they show to me as transparent, just like they are not recognisable

Comment: You can see all the folders, so what does transparent mean? Could you show a screenshot?

Comment: Check the updates on post. I put there the update

Comment: Your updated picture is still the solution view, you may check my answer again.

Comment: The problem is on the solution, that i want to start the api and it doesn´t read any files

Comment: Try to right click these transparent folders/files, then choose **Include In Project**, does this work?